# getStaticProps runs on every request in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use Next JS in my project. I want do only one request in page. And in next docs says that using get Static Props is that's what I need. But in doesnt work for me.

This is my code

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const leaguesCol = await collection(database, 'leagues');
  const leaguesSnapshot = await getDocs(leaguesCol);

  const leagues = leaguesSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

  return {
    paths: leagues.map((item) => ({
      params: {
        id: item.link,
      },
    })),
    fallback: false,
  };
}
```

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const { id } = context.params;
  const leaguesRef = await collection(database, 'highlights');
  const q = query(leaguesRef, where('league', '==', id));
  const leagueSnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  const data = leagueSnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());

  return {
    props: { data },
  };
}
```

But, when i deploy project in Firebase, i see that request happens in every routing to page. For example, in screen my routing between "spain" and "germany" pages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPJ1N.png)

Comment: How are you deploying your project in Firebase? Do you run a build? Remember static paths in NextJS are compiled at buildtime

Comment: i build width "next build && next export"

Comment: firebase has issues from first days to support frameworks it could be still there. Try deploying on vercel or other

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have this issue locally, i run next build and next start and still `getStaticProps` execute on every request, did you find solution? @ИкерКасильяс